# Error when linking .o files using ld on WIndows

Tags: c, windows, gcc, gnu, ld

Two C files are compiled as shown:

`gcc -g -c -Wall -I../include blink.c -o blink.o`

`gcc -g -c -Wall -I../include led/led.c -o led/led.o`

These operations appear to be successful (the correct files are produced).

When attempting to link the two .o files with the command:

`ld -Map blink.map -T make.ld -N -o blink.exe blink.o led/led.o`

This error is returned:

`` undefined reference to `__main' ``

As suggested on another post, I tried adding `-r`, but that instead results in this error shown below:

```
C:\mingw\bin\ld.exe: address 0x0 of blink.exe section `data' is not within region `ram'
C:\mingw\bin\ld.exe: address 0x0 of blink.exe section `bss' is not within region `ram'
C:\mingw\bin\ld.exe: address 0xd0 of blink.exe section `text' is not within region `ram'
C:\mingw\bin\ld.exe: address 0x28 of blink.exe section `.xdata' is not within region `ram'
C:\mingw\bin\ld.exe: address 0x30 of blink.exe section `.pdata' is not within region `ram'
C:\mingw\bin\ld.exe: address 0x40 of blink.exe section `.rdata$zzz' is not within region `ram'
```

I am using Windows 10, and have tried this using both Cygwin64 Terminal and MinGW, but get the exact same result with both.

I am fairly sure that it is not a RAM issue, as there is '320K' (which I believe should be more than enough for a simple program like this) assigned in the `make.ld` file, shown below:

```
ENTRY (main)

MEMORY
{
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 320K /* 0x2000 0000 - 0x2004 FFFF */
    rom : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 1024K /* 0x0800 0000 - 0x080F FFFF */
}

SECTIONS
{
    data :
    {
        _DataStart = . ;
        *(.data)
        _DataEnd   = . ;
    } >ram 

    bss :
    {
        _BssStart = . ;
        *(.bss)
        _BssEnd   = . ;
    } >ram 

    text :
    {
        *(.text)
    } >ram 
}
```

For reference here are the three other files:

blink.c

```c
int main(void)
{
    ledInit();
    while (1)
    {
        ledToggle();
        delay_ms(500);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

led/led.c

```c
#include "../stm32f7/onChipPeripherals.h"            

void ledInit(void)
{
    (*((uint32_t volatile *)(GPIO_A + GPIO_BSRR_OFFSET))) = 0xFFFF0000;
    (*((uint32_t volatile *)(GPIO_A + GPIO_MODER_OFFSET))) = 0x00000010;
}

void ledToggle(void)
{
    if ((*((uint32_t volatile *)(GPIO_A + GPIO_BSRR_OFFSET))) & 0x0000FFFF)
        (*((uint32_t volatile *)(GPIO_A + GPIO_BSRR_OFFSET))) = 0xFFFF0000;
    else
        (*((uint32_t volatile *)(GPIO_A + GPIO_BSRR_OFFSET))) = 0x0000FFFF;
}

void delay_ms(int milliseconds)
{
    long volatile cycles = (milliseconds * CYCLES_PER_MS);
    while (cycles != 0)
        cycles--;
}
```

stm32f7/onChipPeripherals.h

```c
#include <stdint.h>

/* GPIO Registers */
#define GPIO_A                                     (*((uint32_t volatile *)0x40020000))

#define GPIO_MODER_OFFSET                          (0x00) // GPIO port mode register
#define GPIO_OTYPER_OFFSET                         (0x04) // GPIO port output type register
#define GPIO_OSPEEDR_OFFSET                        (0x08) // GPIO port output speed register
#define GPIO_PUPDR_OFFSET                          (0x0C) // GPIO port pull-up/pull-down register
#define GPIO_IDR_OFFSET                            (0x10) // GPIO port input data register
#define GPIO_ODR_OFFSET                            (0x14) // GPIO port output data register
#define GPIO_BSRR_OFFSET                           (0x18) // GPIO port bit set/reset register
#define GPIO_LCKR_OFFSET                           (0x1C) // GPIO port configuration lock register
#define GPIO_AFRL_OFFSET                           (0x20) // GPIO alternate function low register
#define GPIO_AFRH_OFFSET                           (0x24) // GPIO alternate function high register
```

I would hugely appreciate any suggestions or guidance on what to do or try next, as I am a little stuck and unsure from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the correct toolchain for the target architecture. An unqualified `gcc` on cygwin64 is going to try to build the program to run on x64 Windows under `cygwin`.

The error is complaining about section `ram`; but the real issue is using the wrong toolchain. The correct `gcc` is `gcc-arm-embedded -m cortex-m7`. Note that you will need to do the same adjustment with the `ld` command; I don't have a good source but the pattern is usually followed so the `ld` command is most likely `ld-arm-embedded`.

My source for the correct `gcc`: https://github.com/libopencm3/libopencm3/issues/965